# CSS body switcher for menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need help..
I change the body tag class:

```
<body class="front">
<select class="style-change">
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
 </select>


<script>
$('.style-change').change(function(){
    $('body').removeClass();
    $('body').addClass($(this).val());
});

</script>
```

but i need to change then i click on menu - change body style and other menu element....
Then i click on menu i want to change menu AND the class "front" for body in red green or blue

Comment: You want to use anchors instead of a select? What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: And the problem is....? your code must work fine for that. ***see your code in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8f2x8/***

Answer (score 0):

first remove all class from body tag then apply new class.

```
<script>
$('.style-change').change(function(){
    $('body').removeAttr('class');
    $('body').attr('class', $('.style-change option:selected').val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the difference with the code that OP provide? for his needs

Comment: here it select the value from selected item of dropdown and then apply to body class.

Answer (score 0):

**Try :**

```
$('.style-change').change(function(){
    var color = $('option:selected',this).val();
    $('body').removeClass().addClass(color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select.style-change').change(function() {
    var selectedColor = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('body').removeClass().addClass(selectedColor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your jQuery script inside document.ready:

```
$(function() {
     $('.style-change').change(function(){
    $('body').removeClass();
    $('body').addClass($(this).val());
});

  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uWBRDsAcIRDYfWoFLIk2?p=preview)

Comment: yes, but i want to change body style then i click on this menu: <ul>
<li><a href="www.test.com">red</a></li>
<li><a href="www.test111.com)">gree</a></li>
<li><a href="www.test555.com">blue</a></li>
</ul>, not for <select class="style-change">
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
 </select>

Comment: Do you have control over these sites. You can't do that. You  are trying to inject your custom code onto a side and that is not possible in simple means.